# Why does my blog page only show one post?

Tags: wordpress

I didn't think I would encounter this kind of problem in creating a static front page because this seems to be a very trivial customization of wordpress. I am using Thematic as my parent theme. I created a home.php template and pasted the code from the parent's page template into it. I also created two new blank pages named Home and Blog. I set home.php as the template for page Home. Then I went to Settings->Reading and set my front page to a static page and selected page Home. I also set posts page to page Blog. Now when go to my Blog page, I only see a single post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is set for "Blog pages show at most" in Settings>>Reading? Do you have more than one post?

Comment: Yah, I installed test data from wordpress.org. I set it to 10 posts per page. But I found a solution, I didn't assign a page for the posts in Settings->Reading and created a template instead with The Loop in it. Then I used it as the template for my Blog page. It worked. I wonder what effects would this cause for plugins, if there would be any?

Comment: Plugins that use any settings like that work at a much lower level to determine reading settings. If those settings do affect a plugin, it's the plugin's problem.